# Multiple complex shaped buttons in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, bitmap, surfaceview, android-selector

i hope somebody out there might help me out here.

I have a Activity where you can select one out of max. 10 items. When an item is clicked I open a fragment which single purpose is to give the user a choice out of 8 different actions. The fragment contains multiple buttons and must be loaded as fast as possible.

The requirement however is to have a user interface like this:
[image: complex_button]

Every dark section in this picture and the X shall be clickable. I want visual feedback when the user presses a button (the sections get darker).

The problem is that the fragment takes too long to load and that the visual feedback is required. Here is what I already tried to accomplish this:

I have acces to each part of that image in gimp, so I can extract every single part of it.

A) XML-Layout with 9 Buttons. I extracted every item seperately, created a selector for each button and used this class to dispatch the onTouchEvent:

```
private Bitmap b;

private void init(){ //called in every constructor
    b = drawableToBitmap(super.getBackground(), super.getMeasuredWidth(), super.getMeasuredHeight());
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();
    //TODO add Offset
    if (b.getPixel(x,y) == Color.TRANSPARENT){
       return false;
   }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}


public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
        if(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
            return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap(), newWidth, newHeight, true);

        }
    }

    if(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Single color bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel

    } else {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }
    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

This works only with up to 2 or three pictures and consumes a lot of space. After 3 components the buttons begin to lag....

B) I created a surfaceView and painted each part of the image separately. Later I could use the bitmap references to determine which part has been clicked.

I realized that loading all that images takes a long time (even if done in a separate thread), so I decided to display the image in its fully composed state. I used this class for this:

```
   /**
 * Context for Views
 */
private Context context;
/**
 * Thread for painting with 50Hz
 */
private DrawThread drawThread;

/**
 * Boolean storage for indicating that start values has been set
 */
private boolean isInitialized = false;

/**
 * Standard constructor required for android system
 *
 * @param ctx
 * @param attrSet
 */
public BButtonView(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrSet) {
    super(ctx, attrSet);
    BitmapFactory.Options bitopt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitopt.inMutable = true;
    bitopt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    context = ctx;
    base = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.bbutton_all, bitopt);
    SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    this.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

/**
 * Method defining the behavior of this view. It changes the trigger level and the zero level line
 *
 * @param v
 * @param event
 * @return
 */
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:

            break;
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * This class paints on the SurfaceViews canvas
 */
public class DrawThread extends Thread {
    /**
     * State variable for endless loop
     */
    boolean mRun;
    /**
     * Surface on which will be painted
     */
    Canvas mcanvas;
    /**
     * SurfaceHolder for getting and locking the canvas
     */
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    /**
     * Context for this view
     */
    Context context;
    /**
     * Reference to the view to be painted on
     */
    BButtonView bButtonView;

    /**
     * Constructor for this class
     *
     * @param sholder
     * @param ctx
     * @param view
     */
    public DrawThread(SurfaceHolder sholder, Context ctx, BButtonView view) {
        surfaceHolder = sholder;
        context = ctx;
        mRun = false;
        bButtonView = view;
    }

    /**
     * Changes the state variable
     *
     * @param bRun
     */
    void setRunning(boolean bRun) {
        mRun = bRun;
    }

    /**
     * This method will run on another Thread. It will refresh with 50Hz
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        while (mRun) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            surfaceHolder.setFormat(0x00000004); //RGB_565
            mcanvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            if (mcanvas != null) {
                bButtonView.doDraw(mcanvas);
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(mcanvas);
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Override of the surface creation. Initializes the drawThread
 *
 * @param holder
 */
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    drawThread = new DrawThread(holder, context, this);
    drawThread.setRunning(true);
    drawThread.start();
}

/**
 * Will not be used
 *
 * @param holder
 * @param format
 * @param width
 * @param height
 */
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}

/**
 * Frees the thread instance.
 *
 * @param holder
 */
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    drawThread.setRunning(false);
    boolean retry = true;
    while (retry) {
        try {
            drawThread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("BButtonView", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Method defining what will be drawn and in which order. Is called by drawerThread with 50Hz
 *
 * @param canvas
 */
void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    /**Create Background color*/
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    Rect dst = new Rect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    Paint paint = new Paint(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawBitmap(base, null, dst, paint);
    init(canvas);
}

private Bitmap base;
private ArrayList<Bitmap> layers;

private void init(Canvas canvas) {
    if (isInitialized)
        return;
    float h = canvas.getHeight();
    float w = canvas.getWidth();
    layers = new ArrayList<>();

    BitmapFactory.Options bitopt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitopt.inMutable = true;
    bitopt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    bitopt.inSampleSize = ImageCreationAndManipulation.calculateInSampleSize(bitopt, (int) w, (int) h);
    layers.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.bbutton_base, bitopt));
    layers.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.bbutton_a_default, bitopt));
    layers.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.bbutton_b_default, bitopt));
    layers.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.bbutton_c_default, bitopt));
    layers.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.bbutton_d_default, bitopt));
    layers.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.bbutton_e_default, bitopt));
    layers.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.bbutton_f_default, bitopt));
    layers.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.bbutton_g_default, bitopt));
    layers.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.bbutton_h_default, bitopt));
    layers.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.bbutton_m_default, bitopt));
    //TODO generate PixelMap
    isInitialized = true;
}
```

This is what I have so far. However, the fragment is loaded extremely slow and I haven't event implemented the onTouch-Behaviour.

I spent the last week searching for an effiecient way to do this but I can't seem to find an answer.

Do you have any idea how to create this custom shaped multi-button? I have no more ideas on where and what to look for....

help appreciated